# In eclipse, "c:\ \", "c:", what is the difference between the two c disk representations?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I use one of them when I switch different workspace I get a different result. Is there something wrong with my workspace Settings?

Code:

```
public static void function5() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("c:");
    String[] strArr = file.list();
    System.out.println(strArr.length);
    for (String str : strArr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you execute your program on different operating systems?

Comment: no,both in windows

Comment: What different results are you getting?

Comment: If possible put your code here , so that understanding can be more clear.

Comment: when use "c:\\" i can read my c disk but "c:" can not ,however,other in workspace user "c:" can read my c disk

Comment: You have to specify which differences you get. if I execute both variations, the result is the same. The only difference is the `Path`, but the content is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your program as below :

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class TP {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        function5(); 

    } 

    public static void function5() throws IOException {

        File file = new File("c:\\"); 
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("It is a directory");
        }
        System.out.println("Absolute path is " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Canonical path is " + file.getCanonicalPath());
        System.out.println("File path is " + file.getPath());
        String[] strArr = file.list(); 
        System.out.println(strArr.length); 
        for(String str : strArr){ System.out.println(str); 

        } } 

    }
```

you will find that

1) **in case of "c:" (File file = new File("c:"); )**

Absolute path is your current working directory, from where you are executing this java program.

**This is because your workspace is in C: drive**

2) **in case of "C:\" (File file = new File("c:\");**

Absolute path is your C: drive.

**If your workspace is not in c: the output content will be same.**

**EDIT** - Added Canonical path and abstract path as well as you can see in case of c: abstract path is c: only and not your java file location.

Comment: It helps to get the terminology right. Both "C:\" and "C:\some\folder" are *on your C: disk*. The first is in the *root folder*. Now, the problem is that "C:" doesn't specify a folder on the C: drive. It just specifies the C: drive, and any folder on it. Each drive has its own *working directory* (folder). If you specify "C:" you mean the working directory on the C: drive. There are various ways to determine which is your working directory. But there is only one way to specify the root folder, and that's "C:\".

Comment: @Sam.Wang Only one of them will be able to read as that one is correctly mapping to C: drive

Comment: Welcome kindly accept this answer you have to select this answer :)

Answer (score -1):

[this is when i use "c:" it can read my c disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVA3n.png)